# Clearing the history of jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I installed the jupyter notebook on a computer in my lab. But I found out that the person who was using the computer had already set up his jupyter notebook and every time I would log into his account. How could I fix the problem and then create a new account in this computer?

Comment: What OS are you using? Did you install jupyter utilizing the Anaconda environment?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 and I installed it by pip.

Comment: If both are utilizing the same account, of course, both are utilizing the same jupyter installation. If you have admin access to the computer you can create a new user, login with the just created user, and install python3 and a fresh installation of jupyter. Your coworker will have his user account and you will have your user account.

Comment: That's a good idea. But he has left the lab and I think he is not going to use this computer anymore. Do I have to create a new user to get access to a new account?

Comment: Does the account is on that person name or the account is a general account like -- computer-lab or research-laptop? If so, don't create a new account and use the current one. Something to point out is that you need to talk to your Network Admin to follow policy and procedures in order to do such things.

Comment: Okay I get it. Thank you very much!